# What is the best way to store a value that will have to be read by multiple source files but is only know at runtime

Tags: c++

I have a function that runs when the program is started and initializes all variables that will be needed by the program but that can only be obtained during runtime. These variables will have to be read by multiple source files.
What is the best way to store these values?

One of these variables is the file path to the local Appdata directory. I don't know how expensive it is to run the function to get this path so I just want to get it once and store it for later use by the program.

I have tried using a `const std::string` but since (as far as I know) a constant can't be initialized at runtime that option doesn't work. Of course I can just use a global variable but that doesn't really seem like good practice. In addition this could cause problems if the variable accidentally gets edited (I can already feel the pain debugging for hours to find that one line of code).

I know that c# offers `static readonly` which would be perfect for me so I was interested if either something similar to this exists in c++ or if there is an alternative solution better than using a non constant global variable.

Comment: *"since (as far as I know) a constant can't be initialized at runtime"* That's not true. It only applies to `constexpr`.

Comment: just use `static`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function-local static variable. It will be initialized on the first use.

```
const std::string &GetAppDataPath()
{
    static const std::string ret = /*do stuff here*/;
    return ret;
}
```

A global variable (which are initialized at program startup) would be inferior, because you can accidentally [access it before it's initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof) (from an initializer of a different global variable).

Note that you must do everything in the initializer. For example, this would be wrong:

```
const std::string &GetAppDataPath()
{
    static const std::string ret;
    ActuallyGetAppDataPath(&ret);
    return ret;
}
```

If you can't fit everything directly into the initializer, use an immediately-invoked lambda:

```
const std::string &GetAppDataPath()
{
    static const std::string ret = []{
        std::string ret;
        ActuallyGetAppDataPath(&ret);
        return ret;
    }();
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: And how would the variable be accessed? Would you have to call GetAppDataPath() every time you want to access the appdata path?

Comment: @DarkCoder Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thank you a lot - and not just to you but all of the quick answers. I did not really know about the static keyword or at least that it could be used for this!

Answer (score 1):

Let static work for you like this :

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const std::string& get_app_data_folder()
{
    // current_path is a stand in for your getting path to %Appdata% 
    // static means initialized only once at first call to get_app_data_folder
    static std::string path{ std::filesystem::current_path().string() }; 

    return path;
}

int main()
{
    auto path = get_app_data_folder();
    std::cout << path << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yup missed that, fixed